TeamCity: SonarScanner when running in containers
Architecture
We've set up a few TeamCity agents to support containers and thus the Container Wrapper extension. We've been directed to use containers rather than install things on the agents directly. For most things this is fine.
Problem
I'm trying to add SonarScanner to a configuration/build for a .NET solution. SonarScanner is a long-running process that is started by calling its begin command, then doing your build and test steps, then calling its end command. Because the Container Wrapper extension creates a new container for each build step, I can't execute SonarScanner and keep it running so it can do its work.
Potential Solutions

Obviously, installing things on the agents would solve things.
TeamCity has a Docker Compose runner, and containers created in this way seem to last the whole build. Perhaps SonarScanner could run in one of these containers? Details on how this might be accomplished (or how it's impossible) would be appreciated.
??? Some other way I've yet to conceive of.

Question
How can I get SonarScanner to scan my project assuming the Architecture is fixed?
